# How to access ServletConfig in JSF Managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, servletconfig

At the moment, I am try to integrate [Confident CAPTCHA](http://www.confidenttechnologies.com/products/confident-captcha) into my JSF project. The constructor of the class `ConfidentCaptchaClient` is as following:

```
public ConfidentCaptchaClient(String settingsXmlFilePath, HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.ServletConfig servletConfig)
```

This requires a `ServletConfig` argument. How do I get it inside a managed bean?

Comment: @BalusC: Oh, I thought I need to some how get the current Servlet instance that is serving the request. I will try to instantiate an `Servlet` object and see how it goes. Thanks! :D

Comment: @BalusC: :P At the moment, I am actually using PrimeFace's Captcha. However, my application would be used in China and Captcha does not work very nicely over there. Hence, my boss asked me to look for an alternative. :) I believe you must have worked with many captcha solutions. Do you mind recommending a solution or two for me :D

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, it is not a `Servlet`. It just requires access to the `ServletConfig`. That's why I want to get access to a `Servlet` inside my Managed bean so that I can access the `ServletConfig`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack. What [`ServletConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html) is, is basically an object containing parameters of a `Servlet`. You'll find practically the same methods and info in the [`ServletRegistration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html) interface. So it's all the same if you pull the config params off the `ServletContext` itself and populate in a custom implementation of `ServletConfig`. Try this:

1. Retrieve the `ServletContext` object

   ```
   FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   ServletContext servletContext =  (ServletContext) context.getExternalContext(); // Your servlet context here
   ```
2. From the servlet context, get the servlet registration object for the servlet you desire

   ```
   ServletRegistration reg =   servletContext.getServletRegistration("theServlet"); //ServletRegistration contains all the info you'll need to populate a custom ServletConfig object
   ```
3. Use the information you've derived from (2) to populate a custom impl of `ServletConfig`

   ```
   ServletConfig myServletConfig = new MyCustomServletConfig();
   myServletConfig.setInitParams(reg.getInitParameters()); //do a simple transfer of content
   ```

The last step is an oversimplification, but you'll get the idea.

If you were running a previous version of Java EE (pre 3.0), you'll have had access to the `ServletContext#getServlet()` which is now deprecated.